# Windows netsh advfirewall allow ip on port

Tags: windows-7, windows, firewall

I need to create a firewall that can allow only certain ips on certain port. For example allow `1.2.3.4`, `2.2.2.2` and `5.5.5.5` on port `45654`. If `6.6.6.6` tries to access `45654` to deny it.

What command i have tried :

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="application" dir=in action=allow program="C:\application.exe" enable=yes remoteip=64.68.22.49,51.68.11.49/32,LocalSubnet profile=private protocol=TCP localport=42262
```

The problem is that i try to block all and allow ips each and every one of them via windows firewall (interface) but didn't work, either is blocking all or allowing all.

In linux everything is simple :

Linux equivalent

```
-I INPUT -s 0/0 -p tcp  --dport 1080:65535  -j REJECT

-I INPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dports 35001:65000 -j ACCEPT

-I INPUT -p tcp --dport 61605 -j REJECT
-I INPUT -p tcp  -s 103.204.244.3/32 --dport 61605 -j ACCEPT

-I INPUT -p tcp --dport 62814 -j REJECT
-I INPUT -p tcp  -s 103.204.244.3/32 --dport 62814 -j ACCEPT

-I INPUT -p tcp --dport 61525 -j REJECT
-I INPUT -p tcp  -s 103.204.244.3/32 --dport 61525 -j ACCEPT
```

iptables output :

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  178.166.173.55       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:61605
REJECT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:61605 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

ACCEPT     tcp  --  178.150.247.127      0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:62814
REJECT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:62814 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

ACCEPT     tcp  --  178.150.247.127      0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:61525
REJECT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:61525 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

REJECT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpts:1080:65535 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: netsh should work, maybe you leave out the application (just open the port on the firewall for all, the application should listen), maybe you missed the profile (I would set it to "any"), the rest seems okay. Try to configure it through the GUI (never had problems with it).

Comment: i tried via GUI, basically you can either block a port or release a port, no block all and allow only for 5 ips ...

Comment: In the advanced firewall configuration? There is a field for remote IP.

Comment: [see here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd448566(v=ws.10).aspx)